# Sound stop working

Tags: sound

I have a little problem, I touched something related to alsa on the software center, becuase there was a corrupted package that I tried to install (alsa-conexant... or something like this)

After removing it, the sound stop working, now at the taskbar it does not show the sound notification.

I can acess sound config, via "Sound" in Applications, but when I try to choose a Hardware, the list is in blank, there are no devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have removed a package or two too many. Make sure the ubuntu-desktop package is installed, and if not, install it.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: That it does not work, I can not select any hardware on sound config.

Comment: Let's see the APT history log. 'tail -n 50 /var/log/apt/history.log' The output of that command should show what was installed and uninstalled recently.

Comment: Start-Date: 2011-08-20  20:04:08
Remove: alsa-driver-linuxant:i386 (1.0.23.1)
End-Date: 2011-08-20  20:04:35

Comment: That was the last thing I have unistalled, then audio stop working. I purge and install alsa and this driver too. But nothing...